# Why will the \$I_C\$ flow to the opposite direction for an ungrounded system

Tags: current, transformer, ground

Why will the \$I_C\$ flow to the opposite direction for an ungrounded system? The red arrow means the current flowing direction at the when there are three capacitors connected the three lines(A,B,and C)

Now if there is some damage or problems about the capacitor which is connected with line C,so now there is no capacitor connected with C,we can find the direction of \$I_C \$ is opposite than the others,as the black arrow shown

Why does the \$I_A +I_B\$ flow into the line C?there shouldn't be a loop,even if there were,the \$I_C=I_A+I_B\$,so there should be no current,Why will the \$I_C\$ flow to the opposite direction for an ungrounded system

[image]

Answer (score 0):

C is grounded. A and B are floating as represented by the caps. So A/B are biased at a higher or lower DC bias than C.

I feel there is more context to this diagram which you are not revealing. I do not think this diagram is supposed to be representing 3 phase AC currents flowing.

Comment: The voltage amplitude of A,B,and C should be the same,what do you mean about  A/B are biased at a higher or lower DC bias than C.?C is arcing ground